# how to pass arguments to docker run command specific to few scripts but not to entrypoint

Tags: docker

I have created docker file like below,

```
FROM XXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/baseImage:1.0.0

ARG USER_NAME
ARG PASSWD

COPY --chown=sdc:sdc libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar  ${SDC_HOME}/datacollector-jdbc-lib/lib/

#REPLACE CONFIG FILLE
COPY policies/config.properties "${SDC_CONF}"/config.properties

#######################################
# COPY  PIPELINE
#######################################

COPY --chown=sdc:sdc pipelines/fullload/sns.json  "${SDC_HOME}"/

COPY --chown=sdc:sdc postPipeline.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /postPipeline.sh

# Calling the script to post pipeline with argument1: pipeline name
#                    and argument2: pipeline filename
#                    and argument3: username(permission to deploy the pipeline)
#                    and argument3: password of above username
FROM base
RUN sed -i "/^exec.*/i \/postPipeline.sh  'fullload' 'sns.json' ${USER_NAME} ${PASSWD} &"  /docker-entrypoint.sh

#######################################

USER ${SDC_USER}
EXPOSE PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["dc", "-exec"]
```

This works fine, if I hardcode the value. 
But My question is, how can I pass the arguments during run command so that, `postPipeline.sh` will be impacted by those arguments and not the entrypoint.

```
docker run -p port:port buildname <username> <passwd>
```

Because as per docker runbook, these arguments will override the current entrypoint parameter. which I don't want.

Hence, to preserve this as arguments I tried below, but not this is not working as I wanted to pass the arguments in run time not build time.

```
    FROM alpine:latest as base
    ARG USER_NAME
    ARG PASSWD

    ENV USER_NAME=${USER_NAME}
    ENV PASSWD=${PASSWD}

    FROM XXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/baseImage:1.0.0



        COPY --chown=sdc:sdc libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar  ${SDC_HOME}/datacollector-jdbc-lib/lib/

        #REPLACE CONFIG FILLE
        COPY policies/config.properties "${SDC_CONF}"/config.properties

        #######################################
        # COPY  PIPELINE
        #######################################

        COPY --chown=sdc:sdc pipelines/fullload/sns.json  "${SDC_HOME}"/

        COPY --chown=sdc:sdc postPipeline.sh /
        RUN chmod 755 /postPipeline.sh

        # Calling the script to post pipeline with argument1: pipeline name
        #                    and argument2: pipeline filename
        #                    and argument3: username(permission to deploy the pipeline)
        #                    and argument3: password of above username
        FROM base
        RUN sed -i "/^exec.*/i \/postPipeline.sh  'fullload' 'sns.json' ${USER_NAME} ${PASSWD} &"  /docker-entrypoint.sh

        #######################################

        USER ${SDC_USER}
        EXPOSE PORT

        ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
        CMD ["dc", "-exec"]
```

creating multistage just for arguments to me looks like far stretched. So, is there any advise how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass configuration to docker containers in multiple ways -

1. Command line parameters
2. Environment variables
3. Mounting configuration files

For your use case, I understand `docker-entrypoint.sh` will call `postPipeline.sh` internally.

If you have access to modify `docker-entrypoint.sh`, you can make it take the arguments required for `postPipeline.sh`  as well and pass them on internally.

If you have access to modify `postPipeline.sh`, you can make it read the configuration from environment variables.

You can mount a configuration file into the container and modify either `docker-entrypoint.sh` or `postPipeline.sh` to read the arguments from config file.

Comment: yes, I have written both files and I was kind of expecting to make variable available to the intended scripts not to impact entry point. I made changes and used ENV as accepted answers to my question.

Answer (score 0):

`RUN ... postPipeline.sh` is executed in build time so obviously you cannot pass arguments to it on run time. What you could do, is wrapping the calls to the `postPipeline.sh` and `docker-entrypoint.sh` in another script and calling it in the `ENTRYPOINT`.